# return type for j parameter in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I have been using `data.table` for some computation and am wondering what are the possible return types for the `j` parameter so that it stacks up my output correctly?  I know `data.frame` is acceptable so `list` must be as well?  My function returns multiple rows and multiple columns for each `id`. So imagine:

```
dtb <- data.table(id=rep(1:5,20), a=1:100, b=sample(1:100, 100), c=sample(1:100, 100))
f <- function(dt) { return(c(dt$a+1, dt$b+1, dt$c+1))}
dtb[,f(.SD), by=id]
```

This clearly does not work properly.  This does:

```
dtb <- data.table(id=rep(1:5,20), a=1:100, b=sample(1:100, 100), c=sample(1:100, 100))
f <- function(dt) { return(data.frame(a=dt$a+1, b=dt$b+1, c=dt$c+1))}
dtb[,f(.SD), by=id]
```

Constructing these `data.frame`s seems like a really inefficient way to do things. What are some suggestions?  The `by` must be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote  this `c(dt$a+1, dt$b+1, dt$c+1)` you *should* have expected a single vector (plus the group id column. Try this instead:

```
dtb <- data.table(id=rep(1:5,20), a=1:100, b=sample(1:100, 100), c=sample(1:100, 100))
f <- function(dt) { return(list(dt$a+1, dt$b+1, dt$c+1))}
dtb[,f(.SD), by=id]
```

EDIT2 (there was an error in my earlier edit that I only noticed when posting the full code). To the question about "cheaper": Here's a benchmark run that shows list construction to be 'cheaper':

```
flst <- function(dt) { return(list(dt$a+1, dt$b+1, dt$c+1))}
fdf <- function(dt) { return(data.frame(dt$a+1, dt$b+1, dt$c+1))}
require(rbenchmark)
 benchmark(
    lstdt=dtb[ , flst(.SD), by=id], 
    dfdt=dtb[ , fdf(.SD), by=id], 
    replications=10^2
    )
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2  dfdt          100   0.466  2.89441     0.457    0.010          0         0
1 lstdt          100   0.161  1.00000     0.159    0.003          0         0
```

Comment: is it cheaper to construct a data.frame or list?

Comment: A list has many fewer requirements (no rownames, no checking for equal lengths of component) lists and would almost certainly be "cheaper" in terms of number of computing steps.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to th e `j` component is not native `data.table`-speak

It is  worth reading the [data.table wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table) on do's and don't regarding data.table syntax (using `data.frame` is **terrible!**, in terms of performance).

You may also refer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872499/create-an-expression-from-a-function-for-data-table-to-eval),  and perhaps you will start to understand how the using `j` and `list` works.

- You are passing a list of expression that will be evaluated within the data.table (or grouped subset thereof)
- these are *unevaulated* expressions, and (currentl) the function `[` relies on observing `list` to properly evaulated these within the correct environment (the `data.table` or `.SD`, the group subset)

This call will work

```
    dtb[,list(a = a+1, b = b + 1, c = c+1), by = id]
```

As will this (passing an unevaulated expression which happens to be a call to `list(...)`

```
library(plyr) # for as.quoted
my_list <- as.quoted(paste('list(',paste(letters[1:3], '=', letters[1:3], '+1',collapse= ','),')'))[[1]]
my_list
## list(a = a + 1, b = b + 1, c = c + 1)
dtb[,eval(my_list), by = id]
```

There is also the possibility of combining a call of `lapply(.SD, a_function)` in conjunction with `.SDcols`. The `.SDcols` argument lets you pass a string of column names on which want the function to be evaluated, so this will work

```
dtb[, lapply(.SD,base::'+',1),by= id, .SDcols = c('a','b','c')]
```

or

```
dtb[,lapply(.SD, .Primitive('+'),1), by= id, .SDcols = c('a','b','c')]
```

note that I called `base::'+'` or `.Primitive('+')` instead of `'+'`, as data.table cannot cannot find `'+'` as a function

## Benchmarking

Benchmarking these solutions

```
benchmark(
  lstdt=dtb[ , flst(.SD), by=id], 
  dfdt=dtb[ , fdf(.SD), by=id], 
  lapplySD = dtb[, lapply(.SD,base::'+',1),by= id, .SDcols = c('a','b','c')],
  lapplySD2 = dtb[, lapply(.SD,.Primitive('+'),1),by= id, .SDcols = c('a','b','c')]
  just_list = dtb[,list(a = a+1,b=b+1,c=c+1),b=id],
  eval_mylist = dtb[,eval(my_list),b=id],
  replications=10^2

##             test replications elapsed relative user.self 
##  2        dfdt          100    0.36 4.000000      0.34       
##  6 eval_mylist          100    0.09 1.000000      0.10       
##  5   just_list          100    0.11 1.222222      0.10        
##  3    lapplySD          100    0.14 1.555556      0.14  
##  4   lapplySD2          100    0.11      1.1      0.11  
##  1       lstdt          100    0.18 2.000000      0.17
```

- the unevaluated expression (passing the list of expressions) is the fasted, which is consistent with Matthew Dowle's points in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872499/create-an-expression-from-a-function-for-data-table-to-eval)

Comment: the point of the question was that i needed to know what my function needed to return because i could not simply type it into the `j` parameter.  this is very helpful though, thank you!

Comment: Read 2.8 of the [data.table-faq](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf). I think perhaps scoping using `{..}` might be a better approach. Regarding my answer, I answered your specific problem of just adding 1 to a subset of columns [in which case there are 'faster', more data.table-ish approaches.

Comment: ahh ok, i'll check it out. your answer is much appreciated and i +1'd you.